# Red Hat File Copy

Tags: ftp, rhel4

I have setup FTP on Redhat RHEL 4, I want to copy a gz file from a windows machine. The thing is i cant unzip it once its on the linux box, its says its corrupted.

But i can open it ok on windows, i thnk its being corrupted during the copy, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You probably forget to switch the transfer mode to binary. The UNIX/Linux systems handles end of line different from Windows/DOS systems. The FTP do a conversion if the transfer mode is ASCII.
You should read the manual of your FTP kliens how to switch to binary mode. If you are using a command line version you should use the command `binary` or `bin`.

Comment: @ngetha you should accept the answer as a "thank you"..